# Javascript function challenge add(1,2) and add(1)(2) both should return 3

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, javascript, function

A friend of mine challenged me to write a function that works with both of these scenarios

```
add(1,2)  // 3
add(1)(2) // 3
```

My instinct was the write an add() function that returns itself but I'm not sure I'm heading in the right direction.  This failed.

```
function add(num1, num2){
    if (num1 && num2){
        return num1 + num2;
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}

alert(add(1)(2));
```

So I started reading up on functions that return other functions or return themselves.

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-functions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235259/javascript-self-calling-function-returns-a-closure-what-is-it-for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235259/javascript-self-calling-function-returns-a-closure-what-is-it-for

I am going to keep trying, but if someone out there has a slick solution, I'd love to see it!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You tagged this as code-golf, meaning that the shortest possible code will win the contest. If this is your intention, you should remove the code-challenge tag.

Comment: I have an answer [here on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306312/31306453#31306453)

Comment: FYI this is called currying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## JavaScript (as asked)

This is a "correct" way to do it but hardly the golfiest way. It's unclear if you're asking for shortest code (the question looks like it will be closed soon anyway.)

```
function add(a, b) {
    if(typeof b === "undefined")
        return function(c) { return a + c }
    return a + b
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use `b === undefined` here?

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 23 bytes

```
add=(a,b)=>b==+b?a+b:c=>a+c
```

If you are willing to use ES6, you can use fat-arrow functions and conditionals to write the function.

## JavaScript, 55 bytes

```
function add(a,b){return b==+b?a+b:function(c){return a+c}}
```

Here's the same function in regular (current version of) JavaScript.

`b?` will check if b is a non-falsey value

`a+b` if it is, return the sum of a and b

`:c=>a+c` if it's not, return a function with a single argument c which returns the sum of c and a

Comment: @vihan1086 Still doesn't work for `add(1,-1)`.

Comment: ``add=(a,b)=>b==+b?a+b:c=>a+c``.

Comment: @Tyilo didn't consider that as a valid input, fixed